# How to use Continue For within an inner function in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, continue, local-functions

I have an outer function which contains a loop and an inner function where I'm trying to use Continue For. How can I use the Continue For within the inner function. For example:

```
Public Function Create(variable1 As String, variable2 As String) As String
   Dim settingsList = 'Code to store data in list
   For Each setting In settingsList
      ProcessSomething(variable1, variable2)
   Next
Return ""
End Function

Private Function ProcessSomething(variable1 As String, variable2 As String)  As String
   If variable1 = "" Then
      'Log Error
      Continue For
   End If
Return ""
End Function
```

The Private function is called within the Loop of the Public Function, but I see a warning in Visual Studio that says 'Continue For' can only appear inside a 'For' statement. How would you use a Continue For in a case like this or is not possible and not even necessary?

Comment: Unless there's code after the call to `ProcessSomething` that you want skipped, then just `Return`ing (perhaps `Nothing`) early from `ProcessSomething` will have the same effect of moving to the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `Continue For` outside a `For`, as the error is telling you. You're trying to use it in an independent function which may or may not be called from within a loop, so the compiler can't accept your usage of it in case you call the function in a different context.

Instead, make the function return a result, and use that to decide whether to execute `Continue For` or not.

For example:

```
Public Function Create(variable1 As String, variable2 As String) As String
   Dim settingsList = 'Code to store data in list
   For Each setting In settingsList
      If ProcessSomething(variable1, variable2) = True Then
        Continue For
      End If
   Next
Return ""
End Function

Private Function ProcessSomething(variable1 As String, variable2 As String)  As Boolean
   If variable1 = "" Then
      'Log Error
      Return True
   Else
     Return False
   End If
End Function
```